# Refreshing page redirects to wrong URL in React

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, react-router

I have the following routes in my App.js:

```
           <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
                        <Route path='/administrate' component={AdministratePage} />

                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
```

My bundle.js is referenced in my Default/Index.cshtml view :

```
<div id="root" />
<script src="~/Scripts/react/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

After logging on successfully I execute:

```
this.props.history.push('/administrate');
```

... in my LoginPage component which successfully redirects to /administrate

Question: 
**How do I prevent from being redirected to the login page when hitting F5 on the administrate page ?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a page reload all information in memory is lost so in order to stay logged in you will need to persist user session data after login and check for it on initial page load.

Easiest way to do this could be cookies or localStorage.

Comment: I am in the session, there's no problem with that.